# Why am I unable to install the R package stringi?

Tags: r, stringr, stringi, rhadoop

Problem installing `stringi` package during R library installation.

During the installation of the package, I get an error when I connect to the URL and receive "icudt551.zip". However, the current situation is that if you have the file "icudt551.zip" in your Linux "/ home / R" path and you can not connect to the internet, you need to install it.

I need help with how to proceed with the installation.
This is the command I used.

```
Install.packages ("/ contrib / stringr_1.0.1.tar.gz", type = "source", repos = NULL)
```

Comment: did you check that the file `/contrib/stringr_1.0.1.tar.gz` exists?

Comment: What's the error message? There are a few things wrong with your code, but I'm not sure if that's what you've run or just how you've typed it here.

Comment: Are you trying to install `stringr` or `stringi`?  Since `stringr` depends on `stringi`, you'll need to install the latter first.  Also, lowercase `i` in `install.packages`, and no spaces between forward slashes (hopefully that's just copy-paste issues in your post).

Answer (score -1):

Try to do as
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76141710/parse-error-when-installing-packages-from-source-on-the-example-of-package-rms).

In short --- use terminal like this:

```
sudo apt install r-cran-stringi
```

Personally, I had the following in the terminal:

```
r@ma:~$ sudo apt install r-cran-stringi
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  r-cran-stringi
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 729 kB of archives.
After this operation, 1,263 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 https://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye/main amd64 r-cran-stringi amd64 1.5.3-1 [729 kB]
Fetched 729 kB in 1s (1,420 kB/s)      
Selecting previously unselected package r-cran-stringi.
(Reading database ... 363366 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../r-cran-stringi_1.5.3-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking r-cran-stringi (1.5.3-1) ...
Setting up r-cran-stringi (1.5.3-1) ...
r@ma:~$
```

Remark --- delete only in terminal accordingly like
[this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/151941/how-can-you-completely-remove-a-package):

```
sudo apt --purge remove r-cran-stringi
sudo apt autoremove
```

Personally, I had the following in the terminal:

```
r@ma:~$ sudo apt --purge remove r-cran-stringi
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libcmark-gfm-extensions0 libcmark-gfm0 libjs-modernizr libjs-prettify node-highlight.js pandoc pandoc-data
  r-cran-acepack r-cran-backports r-cran-checkmate r-cran-fastmatch r-cran-filehash r-cran-fontbitstreamvera
  r-cran-fontliberation r-cran-fontquiver r-cran-formula r-cran-freetypeharfbuzz r-cran-gdtools r-cran-highr
  r-cran-latticeextra r-cran-polspline r-cran-r.methodss3 r-cran-r.oo r-cran-rcmdcheck r-cran-rversions
  r-cran-sessioninfo r-cran-systemfonts r-cran-tikzdevice r-cran-xml r-cran-xopen
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  r-cran-cliapp* r-cran-devtools* r-cran-hmisc* r-cran-htmltable* r-cran-knitr* r-cran-rmarkdown* r-cran-rms*
  r-cran-roxygen2* r-cran-selectr* r-cran-stringi* r-cran-stringr* r-cran-vdiffr*
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 12 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
After this operation, 20.5 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 366942 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing r-cran-cliapp (0.1.1-1) ...
Removing r-cran-vdiffr (0.3.3+dfsg-1) ...
Removing r-cran-devtools (2.3.2-1) ...
Removing r-cran-rms (6.1-1-1) ...
Removing r-cran-hmisc (4.5-0-1) ...
Removing r-cran-htmltable (2.1.0-1) ...
Removing r-cran-roxygen2 (7.1.1-1) ...
Removing r-cran-rmarkdown (2.6+dfsg-1) ...
Removing r-cran-knitr (1.31+dfsg-1) ...
Removing r-cran-selectr (0.4-2-2) ...
Removing r-cran-stringr (1.4.0-2) ...
Removing r-cran-stringi (1.5.3-1) ...
(Reading database ... 365385 files and directories currently installed.)
Purging configuration files for r-cran-rmarkdown (2.6+dfsg-1) ...

r@ma:~$ sudo apt autoremove
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  libcmark-gfm-extensions0 libcmark-gfm0 libjs-modernizr libjs-prettify node-highlight.js pandoc pandoc-data
  r-cran-acepack r-cran-backports r-cran-checkmate r-cran-fastmatch r-cran-filehash r-cran-fontbitstreamvera
  r-cran-fontliberation r-cran-fontquiver r-cran-formula r-cran-freetypeharfbuzz r-cran-gdtools r-cran-highr
  r-cran-latticeextra r-cran-polspline r-cran-r.methodss3 r-cran-r.oo r-cran-rcmdcheck r-cran-rversions
  r-cran-sessioninfo r-cran-systemfonts r-cran-tikzdevice r-cran-xml r-cran-xopen
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 30 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
After this operation, 178 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 365385 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing pandoc (2.9.2.1-1+b1) ...
Removing libcmark-gfm-extensions0:amd64 (0.29.0.gfm.0-6) ...
Removing libcmark-gfm0:amd64 (0.29.0.gfm.0-6) ...
Removing libjs-modernizr (2.6.2+ds1-4) ...
Removing libjs-prettify (2015.12.04+dfsg-1.1) ...
Removing node-highlight.js (9.18.5+dfsg1-1) ...
Removing pandoc-data (2.9.2.1-1) ...
Removing r-cran-acepack (1.4.1-2+b5) ...
Removing r-cran-checkmate (2.0.0-1+b1) ...
Removing r-cran-backports (1.2.1-1) ...
Removing r-cran-fastmatch (1.1-0-3) ...
Removing r-cran-tikzdevice (0.12.3.1-1) ...
Removing r-cran-filehash (2.4-2-3) ...
Removing r-cran-freetypeharfbuzz (0.2.6+dfsg-1) ...
Removing r-cran-fontquiver (0.2.1-3) ...
Removing r-cran-fontbitstreamvera (0.1.1+dfsg-4) ...
Removing r-cran-fontliberation (0.1.0+dfsg-4) ...
Removing r-cran-formula (1.2-4-1) ...
Removing r-cran-gdtools (0.2.3-1) ...
Removing r-cran-highr (0.8+dfsg-2) ...
Removing r-cran-latticeextra (0.6-29-3) ...
Removing r-cran-polspline (1.1.19-1) ...
Removing r-cran-r.oo (1.24.0-1) ...
Removing r-cran-r.methodss3 (1.8.1-1) ...
Removing r-cran-rcmdcheck (1.3.3-2) ...
Removing r-cran-rversions (2.0.2-1) ...
Removing r-cran-sessioninfo (1.1.1-4) ...
Removing r-cran-systemfonts (1.0.0-1) ...
Removing r-cran-xml (3.99-0.5-1) ...
Removing r-cran-xopen (1.0.0-2) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.9.4-2) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.31-13+deb11u6) ...

r@ma:~$
```